# ошибка expected primary-expression before ',' token

Tags: c++, arduino, макросы

Я не могу запустить скетч ардуино из-за этой ошибки. Делаю в VS Code PlatformIo.

Код:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

int serialGet;

#define led = D0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}

void loop()
  {
    int serialGet = Serial.read();

    if (serialGet > 1) {
      serialGet = 0;
    }

    else if (serialGet == 1) {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      Serial.println("LED = HIGH");
    }

    else {
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
      Serial.println("LED = LOW");
    }
```

Я хотел сделать так: если в Serial Monior отправить 1, тогда светодиод загорелся, если 0, тогда он бы выключился.

Comment: В тексте ошибки указывается номер строки

Comment: тут много ошибок одна из них src\main.cpp:11:19: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define led = D0;
```

приводит к тому, что, например,

```
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
```

превращается перед компиляцией в

```
pinMode(= D0;, OUTPUT);
```

`#define` просто заменяет текст, не зная ничего о том, что такое синтаксис C. Так что все `led` заменяются, как вы попросили, на `= D0;`, после чего компилятор *пытается* это все скомпилировать...

Answer (score 1):

После #define led уберите = и после D0 уберите ;
Должно быть вот так:

```
    #define led D0
```